# Decorating DIV and using full page width via CSS / CSS :before and :after

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a page that looks code wise like

```
<div class="green">  
  <span class="orange">s1</span>
  <span class="orange">s2</span>
</div>
```

but that should be formated via CSS like:
[image: Layout explanation]

- The surrounding black frame shows the full page in the browser. (Think of `<body></body>`)
- The red frame is a fixed width and fixed hight basically empty space that should be added by the CSS `.green:before` (I'm using it's ability to format it's borders for a visual effect)
- The green frame shows the real content that should be as wide as necessary to contain both `<span>` in one line
- The blue frame should be created by the CSS `.green:after`, has a fixed height and should take up all the space till the right border of the page - i.e. it must have a variable width.

Required browsers are the modern ones (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) in recent versions. No need to take care of IE. Mobile browsers would be great, though.

How can I achieve that? (All my attempts failed sooner or later...)

A jsFiddle with this example code is at http://jsfiddle.net/X2MDG/

Comment: Can I just check you haven't copied and pasted your code as your class name tags aren't closed properly -> "orange". Also start a jFiddle, that way people can play with it till its correct.

Comment: Thank, the code was written for this example, so no Copy&Paste problem here :)

Comment: "the green frame [...] should  be as wide as necessary to contain both <span>", so if the spans grow big enough a horizontal scrollbar should appear in the black (or green?) div? And in that case the blue div should be 0px wide?

Comment: Good question! It would be enough to allow the result to be undefined... Probably an `overflow:hidden` would look nicest.

Comment: An additional note: if necessary it might be ok to add an surrounding `<div class="sourround">` - I'll also update the jsFiddle accordingly

Comment: Still thinking about this. One more question: can you elaborate on why you want to use the `:before` pseudo selectors, instead of just actual elements (e.g. `div`s)?

Comment: Well, the HTML structure is mostly fixed as this will be "only" an additional design to an existing web application. And this task here is only for decoration so I could hardly ask for a different DOM structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no way to satisfy *all* your constraints. The main things that don't seem to have a CSS solution are:

- Controlling the width of just the green bit can't be done without affecting the width of the red `:before` and blue `:after` content. As you mention in the comments to the question, using a different DOM structure is not an option.
- The blue (`:after`) content should take up all space not needed by the green (main) content.
- The fixed height of red/blue may require some clearing on the elements below the entire div.

So, as far as I could tell, the question as you asked it doesn't have a 100% satisfying answer. Either way, here's the code I came up with researching this problem, perhaps it can help you or others stumbling on this question. See either [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLZDH/) or the code below:

```
<div id="page">
    <div class="green">
        <span>Orange 1.</span>
        <span>Orange 2. Which can be really wide.</span>
    </div>
    <p style="clear: both;">Black is the page. Clearing is
            needed because the red and blue boxes are not in the 
            flow but do have quite some height.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#page { 
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2px;
}

div.green:before {
    content: 'red / before';
    border: 2px solid red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.green {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

div.green:after {
    content: 'blue / after';
    border: 2px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
}

div.green span {
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: Although you couldn't solve my question I'm happy that I found a solution to my task that was the origin of the question: http://jsfiddle.net/K86Ua/

Comment: Ah yes, now I can see what you were after. Glad my answer could help.